# Upper density of subsets of an amenable group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, amenability

Let $G$ be an amenable group (so locally compact Hausdorff) and also assume it is second countable if needed. My question is that what are the standard ways (across literature) of defining the upper density for a subset of $G$?

If we are talking about $\mathbb{N}$, then given a Folner sequence $\mathcal{F}=\{F_n: n\in \omega\}$ (basically each $F_n$ is finite and for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|(m+F_n)\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|}=0$), then the upper density associated with $\mathcal{F}$ can be $\bar{d}_\mathcal{F}(A)=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|A\cap F_n|}{|F_n|}$.

One way to define the density is to replace the counting measure by the Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ and the Folner sequence in a more general sense ($F_n$ are compact sets now) and we can say $\bar{d}_\mathcal{F}(A)=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{\mu^*(A\cap F_n)}{\mu(F_n)}$, where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure (I want to define density for any subset $A$).

Another way is to say $\bar{d}(A)=\sup\{\alpha: \text{for every finite }H\subset G \text{ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite $K$ with }\frac{|hK\Delta K|}{|K|}<\varepsilon\; \forall h\in H \text{ and }\frac{|A\cap K|}{|K|}\geq \alpha\}$.

I'm not a group theorist nor topologist and hopefully this question is okay here. Thanks.

Comment: One difficulty is the dependence on the Følner sequence. For instance, take $X=\bigcup_n [2^n,2^n+3n]$, and $F_n=\bigcup_{k=0}^n[2^k+n,2^k+2n[$. Then $F_n$ has cardinal $n^2$ and boundary of cardinal $2n$, so is Følner. But $F_n\subset X$ while $X$ has natural density zero. Only forcing $F_n$ to cover won't be enough to fix the issue (change $F_n$ to $F_n\cup [-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]$ if necessary). In $\mathbf{Z}^2$ one has less artificial examples with $F_n=[-n,n]\times [-n^2,n^2]$ and $X=\{(x,y):|x|\le |y|\}$ which has density zero w.r.t this choice.

Comment: So maybe one way is to look over \emph{all} Folner sequences?

Comment: The problem with this is that you have disjoint ones, i.e. two Følner sequences and two disjoint subsets which have density 1 for one and zero for the other; in particular the density will never be independent of the Følner sequence apart from being in $\{0,1\}$. The notion "subset that has density 0 for every Følner sequence" is thus quite restrictive. Still it seems not void, i.e., not reduced to finite subsets (excludes $\bigcup [2^n,2^n+n]$, but seems to include $\bigcup\{2^n\}$).

Comment: By the way I forgot to say, but we can always consider $\sup m(X)$ when $m$ ranges over invariant means. Probably it means the same as the supremum over all Følner sequences of the upper densities wrt the Følner sequence. Nevertheless it's frustrating that it maps $\bigcup [2^{2^n},2^{2^n}+n]$ to 1.

Comment: More generally, in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$, $\sup m(X)=1$ if and only if $X$ contains arbitrarily large intervals, which is equivalent to the notion of a "thick" set (as defined in my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

In the case that $G$ is discrete, what you've defined last as $\bar{d}(A)$ is usually considered *the* upper (Banach) density of $A$. Moreover, in this case $\bar{d}(A)$ is the supremum of $\bar{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)$ over all Folner sequences $\mathcal{F}$ (or nets in the uncountable case).

Recall also that a discrete group $G$ is amenable if and only if it admits at least one Folner sequence (or net) if and only if it admits a left-invariant finitely additive probability measure on its subsets. So another equivalent formulation of $\bar{d}(A)$ in this case is:
$$
\bar{d}(A)=\sup\{\mu(A):\text{$\mu$ is a left-invariant finitely additive probability measure on $G$}\}.
$$

In the non-discrete case, all of the same facts are true if we use compact sets instead of finite sets. In particular, a locally compact group $G$ (with Haar measure $\eta$) is amenable if and only if for any compact $H\subseteq G$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a Borel set $K\subseteq G$, with $0<\eta(K)<\infty$, such that $\eta(hK{\vartriangle} K)/\eta(K)<\epsilon$ for all $h\in H$.

In this case, if one defines $\bar{d}(A)$ analogously (for Borel $A$), then
\begin{align*}
\bar{d}(A) &= \sup\{\bar{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A):\text{$\mathcal{F}$ is a Folner net for $G$}\}.\\
&= \sup\{\mu(A):\text{$\mu$ is a left-invariant finitely additive Borel probability measure on $G$}\}.
\end{align*}

A final comment is that in groups like $\mathbb{Z}$, there are other "canonical" upper densities, such as the upper asymptotic density:
$$
\bar{\delta}(A)=\limsup_n|A\cap [\text{-}n,n]|/(2n+1).
$$
But notice that this is just $\bar{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)$ for a particular choice of Folner sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$. So in more general groups $G$, one can work with upper densities defined by "special" Folner sequences too.

Edit: The discussion above I think motivates some further remarks about combinatorics. For simplicity, let $G$ be a countable discrete amenable group. Then the notion of "density $0$ with respect to every Folner sequence", i.e. $\bar{d}(A)=0$, is a useful notion of "sparse". For example Szemeredi's Theorem can be rephrased as saying that (in $\mathbb{Z}$) if $\bar{d}(A)>0$ then $A$ contains arbitrarily large finite arithmetic progressions).

For some easier facts, define the *lower Banach density with respect to a Folner sequence $\mathcal{F}$* to be $\underline{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)=\liminf|A\cap F_n|/|F_n|$. The *lower Banach density* is then
$$
\underline{d}(A)=\inf\{\underline{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A):\text{$\mathcal{F}$ a Folner sequence}\}
$$

Then some basic combinatorial facts are:

1. $\bar{d}(A)=1-\underline{d}(G\backslash A)$ for any $A$ (this works at the level of Folner sequences.
2. $\underline{d}(A)>0$ if and only if $G=FA$ for some finite $F\subseteq G$ (i.e., $A$ is *syndetic*).
3. $\bar{d}(A)=1$ if and only if for any finite $F\subseteq G$, there is some $g\in G$ such that $Fg\subseteq A$ (i.e., $A$ is *thick*).

A final combinatorial notion is that of a *piecewise syndetic* set, which is a set $A$ such that $FA$ is thick for some finite $F\subseteq G$. Then another fact that is used a lot is that if $A$ is piecewise syndetic then $\bar{d}(A)>0$ (but the converse fails in general).

We also have the following facts.

1. $\underline{d}(A)=\inf\{\mu(A):\text{$\mu$ is a left-invariant finitely additive probability measure on $G$}\}$.
2. For any set $A$ there are Folner sequences $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\bar{d}(A)=\bar{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)$ and $\underline{d}(A)=\underline{d}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)$.

In additional to Szemeredi's Theorem, other well-known results are:

1. (Jin) If $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ are such that $\bar{d}(A),\bar{d}(B)>0$, then $A-B$ is piecewise syndetic. This is a more difficult variation of the easier fact that if $\bar{d}(A)>0$ then $A-A$ is syndetic.
2. (Moreira, Richter, Robertson) If $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$ is such that $\bar{d}(A)>0$ then $A$ contains $B+C$ for some infinite sets $B$ and $C$. This was originally conjectured by Erdos as a replacement for the failure of a density version of Hindman's Theorem.

Comment: so $\bar{d}(A)$ is only defined for $\eta$-measurable $A$'s?

Comment: Yes, probably. I have to admit that my familiarity with this  largely focused in the discrete case (I'll add this for safety).

Comment: thanks for the info. I was thinking maybe we can do outer measure in the definition of $\bar{d}_\mathcal{F}$, then it will make sense for all subsets. But maybe this will yield too many paradoxical examples.

Comment: That's a good question.  There may be some discussion of this in Paterson's book "Amenability". Unfortunately my copy is in my office, which I can't access at the moment.  I see now that I didn't fully appreciate this part of your question. So perhaps someone will post a better answer.

Comment: I guess one thing is that, if your precise definition of $\bar{d}(A)$ is well-defined in the sense that for any finite $H$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is such a $K$, then $G$ is amenable as a discrete group. So $\bar{d}(A)$ is the upper Banach density with respect to the counting measure, and can be applied to all subsets of $G$.

Comment: yeah that definition completely ignores the Haar measure, which does not seem to do justice to many things.

Comment: Just to add something to the already well written answer, there's an account of the relation between Szemeredi's theorem and Furstenberg-Zimmer's theorem in the excellent book of Kerr and Li about ergodic theory, where they not only treat $\mathbb{Z}$, but general discrete groups acting on locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: So Thickly syndetic sets fit in this picture? $A$ is thick if for any finite $F \subset G$, $\cap_{f \in F} fA \neq \emptyset$. The notion "thickly syndetic" is defined by: $A$ is thickly syndetic if for any finite $F \subset G$, $\cap_{f \in F} fA$ is a syndetic set.

Comment: @ARG Yes this notion fits with the others. A set is thickly syndetic if and only if it's complement is not piecewise syndetic (somewhat analogous to how a set is thick if and only if its complement is not syndetic).

Comment: @GabeConant thanks! so if $A$ is such that $\overline{d}(A^{\mathsf{c}}) =0$, then $A$ is thickly syndetic (but the converse fails)?

Comment: @ARG Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dual description of $\overline d$ which goes back to Banach and Følner (in the general countable case), see [Theorem 6 of Granirer](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=283171). For locally compact groups it should be more or less the same if you deal with the means defined on $L^\infty$ with respect to the Haar measure.